# How to make ffmpeg re-encode an vp9 webm with alpha into a vp9 webm with alpha

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9

I am trying to find optimal parameters for encoding a transparent video using ffmpeg in my scenario, and as a test, I have been re-encoding a pre-made transparent .webm (vp9 with alpha channel, made using python vidgear) like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i pre-made.webm pre-made-remade.webm
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0york0~18.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~18.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp
--enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libzimg --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pre-made.webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:01:11.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1107 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1514x1910, SAR 1:1 DAR 757:955, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.91.100 libvpx-vp9
      DURATION        : 00:01:11.040000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55927254b0c0] v1.7.0
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55927254b0c0] Neither bitrate nor constrained quality specified, using default CRF of 32
Output #0, webm, to 'pre-made-remade.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 1514x1910 [SAR 1:1 DAR 757:955], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      DURATION        : 00:01:11.040000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 1776 fps=8.9 q=0.0 Lsize=    6159kB time=00:01:11.00 bitrate= 710.6kbits/s speed=0.354x
video:6146kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.214488%
```

According to the ffmpeg logs, the libvpx-vp9 is correctly being chosen, and alpha_mode is 1, which bodes well.
However, when actually viewing the video, the video is no longer trasparent.

How could I force ffmpeg to keep the alpha channel when re-encoding the video? (This also applies when trying to merge audio into the .webm)

Bonus question: what arguments do you recommend for efficient vp9 encoding? I have tried using `-threads 16 -speed 4 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -row-mt 1` but it seems to fail at fully utilizing all my CPU cores when encoding with the alpha channel (when piping frames from my python script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the line

```
Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv) ...
```

The `yuv420p` indicates that ffmpeg hasn't detected alpha in the input, else it would be `yuva420p`. To export alpha from VP9 streams, you need to use libvpx decoders, so

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i pre-made.webm ...
```